# Using cmd-Errorcodes with System-restriction

Tags: cmd, plc

**System restrictions explanation:** 
I am using a plc-functionblock [NT_StartProcess](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35042443.html&id=) to use cmd.exe, but due to using the functionblock have some restricting factors: Needs to call one executable (which could call others like cmd.exe), maximum stringsize of command of 255 and the command needs to be in one single line/can't be split up into 2 commands. If either cmd.exe or powershell.exe are called, they need to be closed (for example with /C in cmd) after execution.

I am calling an executable, and storing the returned Error-codes in a .txt document.
I want to replicate following behaviour of 2 commands:

```
C:\RootFolder> Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters
 ...Testexecutable.exe is doing sth
C:\RootFolder> echo %ERRORLEVEL% > Testfile.txt
```

This always has correct and expected behaviour.
Now, due to the system restrictions, the 2 commands have to be combined. The executable-path, that im giving to the functionblock could be cmd or powershell, but can't be of Testexecutable.exe, because the only parameters, that can be given to Testexecutable.exe change the behaviour, but can't handle the output, therefore i couldn't access the Error-codes.

I haven't been able to use something like

```
    cmd.exe /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > Testfile.txt"
```

because the previous value of %ERRORLEVEL% before cmd.exe gets called is saved.

---

E.g:

```
C:RootFolder> cd
C:RootFolder>
C:RootFolder> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
C:RootFolder> cmd.exe /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > Testfile.txt"
```

In this example, 0 is saved in Testfile.txt. Other example:

```
C:RootFolder> cd t
Can't find path...
C:RootFolder> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
C:RootFolder> cmd.exe /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > Testfile.txt"
```

In this example 1 gets saved in Testfile.exe.

---

-> %ERRORLEVEL% gets replaced by its integer value before Testexecutable.exe is called.
The supposed output in the example is always 5.

Is there a way to "delay" the replacement of %ERRORLEVEL% to after the previous command is executed? Is there another way to get the Error-codes of an executable?

I previously assumed this as a timing problem ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68221066/timeout-without-affecting-errorlevel)) before the behaviour of the replacement of %ERRORLEVEL% being pointed out by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi).

Comment: Have you tried just escaping the `%` characters, so that the value of `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not read and expanded when your command is passed to the other `cmd.exe` instance. e.g. `cmd.exe /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo ^%ERRORLEVEL^% > Testfile.txt"`. Or alternatively you could try delayed expansion, `cmd.exe /V /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo !ERRORLEVEL! > Testfile.txt"`.

Comment: EH. @Compo Well it works. Not sure how but: Using
`cmd.exe /V /C "Testexecutable.exe --Testparameters & echo !ERRORLEVEL!"`
Im still confused and will read into /V and !ERRORLEVEL! trying to understand them and then try to give a proper answer to the question. THANK YOU SO MUCH, I've been staring at this for hours (no experience with cmd).

Comment: Well Marcus, you could have been staring at it for at least eleven hours less, had you followed my advice, and provided this information, when I asked for it in your previous incarnation of this same problem!